# Просмотр запросов SQLite3

Tags: sqlite3, sql

Есть программа, использующая SQLite3. Как можно просмотреть, какие запросы посылаются к бд?

Comment: если вообще - то нужно пересобрать sqlite c опцией -DSQLITE_DEBUG и можно получить в консоль много всего хорошего. Но если используется какой-либо скриптовый язык, то можно просто драйвер бд немного подстроить и он все сам напишет.

Answer (score 1):

В смысле посмотреть?  Какие напишешь, такие и будут. Физически их не сможешь понаблюдать. Сама по себе бд похожа на текстовые файлы в папке. для запросов используется db api 2 и обычный sql язык.
не знаю на чём пишете, приведу пример на python:

```
import sqlite3 as db - ну тут всё ясно.
conn = db.connect('main.db') # создаст соединение с существующей базой или создаст новую
    c = conn.cursor() - получаем курсор

c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user
(login text, password text) ''')
```

создаст таблицу user, если не существует
 и создаст в ней 2 поля login и password типа текст

```
name = raw_input('введите имя')
pwd = raw_input('введите пароль')
c.execute("INSERT INTO user(login, password) VALUES (?, ?)", (name,pwd,))
```

спросим имя и пароль у пользователя или можем сразу не спрашивая подставить вместо вопросов и засунем значения в нашу базу main.db, в таблицу user, но этого мало, чтобы они там остались после выхода, нужно ещё записать изменения:

```
conn.commit()
```

После того, как в базе что-то имеется, можно уже делать запросы:

```
c.execute("SELECT password FROM user WHERE user.login=?", (name,))
c.execute("SELECT password FROM user")
c.execute("SELECT * FROM user")
```

в первом запросе мы выбираем поле password c таблицы user, где login соответствует имени (в данном случае ввёденному ранее или можно сразу вместо вопроса указать имя
во втором запросе мы выбираем все пароли (password) c таблицы user
в третьем запросе мы выбираем всё из таблицы user

после того, как определились с запросом и с тем что должны получить, пишем в первом случае:

```
print c.fetchone()[0]
```

так мы выведем то, что будет в поле password в первом случае
можно, например, присвоить это значение какой-то переменной, для того чтобы сравнить с чем-то или для каких-то других целей.

в третьем случае, нам потребуется вызвать и скажем в цикле распечатать всё что имеется:

```
for i in c.fetchall():
```

print 'логин - ' i[0]
print 'пароль' - i[1]

Вот так и происходят запросы, они могут быть разными, могут одновременно быть из разных таблиц, это уже нужно смотреть особенности синтаксиса sql для своих задач. ну и в конце нужно закрыть соединение

```
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Хм. Никак. Содержимое можно глянуть SQLiteStudio.